# Batch process all files in directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Right now i have a batch job I wrote that calls another file and passes in the variables that executable needs to run (password and filename).

Ex:

```
> cd f:\test\utils 
> admin import-xml -Dimport.file=f:\DB\file1.xml  -Dadmin.db.password=test123
```

I wrote a job that does this, but found out that there would be multiple files.

The username and password never change but the filename differs for like 15 different xml files--with maybe more coming soon.

The files will always be located in the same folder. Instead of ending up with like 15-20 jobs (one for each file), can I write something that will process each file located in this directory. And either wait till one is completed before the next or I can add a 3 min sleep before it starts the next file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
pushd C:\test\utils
for %%F in (F:\DB\*.xml) do (
   admin import-xml "-Dimport.file=%%~dpnxF" -Dadmin.db.password=test123
)
popd
```

The `%%~dpnxF` expands to **d**‎rive, **p**‎ath, base‎**n**‎ame and e‎**x**‎tension of the current file.

If you intend to set *and* use environment variables (`%foo%`) in that loop, read `help set` first before you get into trouble.

Comment: Awesome. Able to use this to achieve what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how to *avoid* the trouble of using `set` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Snekse, the magic word there is *delayed variable expansion*. It's something I have to explain in every second batch file answer I give. It's well explained in `help set` too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, tastybento. It was indeed correct (but I took the liberty of changing the variable name to make it easier to understand); alas there was a number of reviewers with no idea what they were reviewing who rejected it. To those reviewers: If you don't *understand* an edit, you can skip reviewing it and leave it to those who do. None of you have any visible batch file experience (at least on SO).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `for` command.  Something like this in a batch file:

```
for %%f in (*.xml) do call myotherbatch.bat %%f
```

Assuming that the `admin` command you are running doesn't return until the job is finished, the above loop would process them sequentially.

If you run the command at the prompt (as opposed to in a batch file), only use a single %.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in f:\DB\*
do
   admin import-xml -Dimport.file="$file" -Dadmin.db.password=test123
done
```