# How to batch edit multiple PDF files with the same edit?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, command-line

So the scenario is that a number of PDF files have been produced (300 +) but they all need to be edited in the same way before being used. I can't change the way that they are produced but I would like to be able to remove the first page from each of the PDFs. Is this possible using command prompts or using some other programme?

I can the pdftk in command prompt but at the moment this just does one file at a time and I have to specify the file name and output. Does anyone know if it is possible to have command prompt pick up all files in a folder and delete the first page from them?

Comment: Search for similar questions, please. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642021/batch-process-all-files-in-directory).

Comment: I can't get the %%f and the for /F command to work. If my folder is called Test PDFs and each PDF is called Test1, Test2, Test3 etc How do I then get my code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Nuance Power PDF Advanced has a batch editor capability for multiple file edits for the same thing, but it is limited.